# How to find a factorial, and catch exceptions for invalid input

Tags: python

This is my program to find the factorial of a number. I would like help to make it so that a negative number would run the same code as Value error, so that count decreases by -1, instead of returning an error. Any advice on how i could structure the code better would be helpful too.

The code starts below:

```
c = ""
long = ""
factorial_number = 1
count = 3
attempts_left = ""

while count != 0:
    try:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of" + attempts_left ))
        break
    except:
        ValueError or number < 0
        print("Invalid answer")
        count -= 1
        attempts_left = ", " + str(count) + " attempts remaining."
        if count == 1:
            attempts_left = attempts_left = ", " + str(count) + " attempt remaining."

if count == 0:
    print("NO MORE ATTMEPTS")
else:
    if number == 0:
        factorial_number = 1
        print("Your factorial number is 1")
    else:
        for interger in range(1,number +1, 1):
            factorial_number = interger * factorial_number
            a = (str(factorial_number)) + " "
            long = long + c + str(interger)
            if int(interger) > 0:
                c = " * "

        print(" The equation is " + long + " = "+a)
```

Comment: Several things here: You can't test for number<0 in the except as it won't be executed if the try doesn't cause an error. Your except should be `except ValueError:` not `except:`, then ValueError. If you want the `number<0` and ValueError to run the same code, you can't unless you make it into a function and call it.

Answer (score 3):

You can name multiple exceptions in the except clause, for example:

```
try:
  number = int(input(...))
  assert number >= 0
except (ValueError, AssertionError):
   print("Invalid answer")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code Review:

- As already noted, the `except` clause was not implemented properly
- `factorial_number` and `long` accumulate with each loop and aren't cleared

### New Implementation:

- As per **"Any advice on how i could structure the code better would be helpful too."**
- Use [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) so you don't have to convert numbers to strings
- Everything inside a function
- Let the `while` loop be broken with `pass`, then try to convert `number` to `int`.  Any letters will result in a `ValueError`.

  - `int('10')` works
  - `int('10.5')` doesn't work; `int(float(10.5))` is used to also catch decimal numbers.
- Handle non-numeric characters as an exception, so a different statement can be printed.  Negative numbers are caught with the `if` condition, and print a different statement.

  - Alternatively, use an `assertion`, as shown in the [solution by pauliner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149160/how-to-find-a-factorial-and-catch-exceptions-for-invalid-input/58149223#58149223), to catch both types of invalid input.
- Removed separate handling of `number = 0`
- `number`, `long`, and `factorial_number` are reset with each iteration of the `while` loop, so they don't continue to accumulate from the previous iteration.

```py
def get_factorial():

    def failed(value: int) -> str:
        return f'{value} failed attempts remaining.'

    def game_over(value: int):
        if value == 0:
            print('NO MORE ATTEMPTS')

    count = 3
    while count != 0:
        number = None
        long = 1
        factorial_number = 1

        try:
            number = input(f"Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, {failed(count)} Type 'pass' to quit." )

            if number.lower() == 'pass':
                print('Thank you for playing!')
                break

            number = int(float(number))

            if number < 0:
                print("Negative numbers are not valid.")
                count -= 1
                game_over(count)

            else:
                for integer in range(1, number + 1, 1):
                    factorial_number *= integer
                    if integer > 1:
                        long = f'{long} * {integer}'
                    else:
                        long = f'{integer}'

                print(f'The equation is {number}! = {long} = {factorial_number}')

        except ValueError as e:
            print('You input something other than a number')
            count -= 1
            game_over(count)
```

#### Usage:

```py
get_factorial()

# Output 1:
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 3 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. a
You input something other than a number
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 2 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. -1
Negative numbers are not valid.
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 1 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. 0
The equation is 0! = 1 = 1
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 1 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. 1
The equation is 1! = 1 = 1
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 1 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. 2
The equation is 2! = 1 * 2 = 2
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 1 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. 9
The equation is 9! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 = 362880
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 1 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. pass
Thank you for playing!


# Output 2:
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 3 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. -1
Negative numbers are not valid.
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 2 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. é
You input something other than a number
Please enter a number above one to find the factorial of, 1 failed attempts remaining. Type 'pass' to quit. a
You input something other than a number
NO MORE ATTEMPTS
```